# "could not deduce ... from the context ...", despite context holding what's necessary

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, ghc, typeclass

The following file fails to compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
module AltMonad.Monoid where

import AltMonad.Category
import Prelude (curry)

class Category c
   => Monoid i p c m where
  mid   :: i `c` m
  mcomb :: (m `p` m) `c` m

class Monoid () (,) (->) m
   => HaskellMonoid m where
  empty  :: m
  append :: m -> m -> m

instance Monoid () (,) (->) m
      => HaskellMonoid m where
  empty  = mid ()
  append = curry mcomb
```

It gives the errors:

```
[3 of 3] Compiling AltMonad.Monoid  ( AltMonad\Monoid.hs, interpreted )

AltMonad\Monoid.hs:24:12:
    Could not deduce (Monoid () p0 (->) m)
      arising from a use of `mid'
    from the context (Monoid () (,) (->) m)
      bound by the instance declaration
      at AltMonad\Monoid.hs:(22,10)-(23,24)
    The type variable `p0' is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      empty :: m (bound at AltMonad\Monoid.hs:24:3)
    In the expression: mid ()
    In an equation for `empty': empty = mid ()
    In the instance declaration for `HaskellMonoid m'

AltMonad\Monoid.hs:25:18:
    Could not deduce (Monoid i0 (,) (->) m)
      arising from a use of `mcomb'
    from the context (Monoid () (,) (->) m)
      bound by the instance declaration
      at AltMonad\Monoid.hs:(22,10)-(23,24)
    The type variable `i0' is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      append :: m -> m -> m (bound at AltMonad\Monoid.hs:25:3)
    In the first argument of `curry', namely `mcomb'
    In the expression: curry mcomb
    In an equation for `append': append = curry mcomb
Failed, modules loaded: AltMonad.Category, AltMonad.Hask.
```

It seems to me that I'm giving the right context, but I don't know how to convince GHC of this.

---

Related files:

**`AltMonad.Category`**

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
module AltMonad.Category where

import AltMonad.Hask

class Category cat where
  id  :: cat a a
  (.) :: b `cat` c -> a `cat` b -> a `cat` c

instance Category Hask where
  id    = \x -> x
  g . f = \x -> g (f x)
```

**`AltMonad.Hask`**

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
module AltMonad.Hask where

type Hask = (->)
```

Comment: [This](http://lpaste.net/4907387790838202368) has the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs because when you call `mid ()`, it has the type `Monoid () p0 (->) m => i -> m`, and there is nothing constraining `p0` to be the particular `p` you chose since `p0` does not appear on the right hand side of the `=>` sign in the type signature.  One way to work around this is through the `FunctionalDependencies` extension:

```
-- ...

class Category c => Monoid i p c m | m -> p where
    mid   :: c i m
    mcomb :: c (p m m) m

-- ...

instance Monoid () (,) (->) m => HaskellMonoid m where
    empty  = mid ()
    append = curry mcomb
```

However, this won't work for `append`, as the variable `i` now has to be constrained.  This just means that we need to have it dependent on our choice for `m` as well:

```
class Category c => Monoid i p c m | m -> i, m -> p where
    -- ...
```

And now it'll compile.  Whether or not this is what you want to do, I don't know, but I do know that it'll get your code compiling.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't used FunctionalDependencies before, but it solves my problem. I'll look into it more fully.

Comment: @BertieWheen The `FunctionalDependencies` extension is useful, but you may get more mileage out of the `TypeFamilies` extensions which can often replace it.  It's a bit more complex, but it allows more flexibility.  For example, with these functional dependencies you'll only be able to vary the `Category` instance, not the `i` or `p` variables.  Essentially it restricts the amount of polymorphism in your class such that it can solve the constraints, but this obviously means that it's less general.